# Форматирование системного диска средствами Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

Как отформатировать диск C средствами самой системы? Внезапно format C: не работает

Answer (score 0):

Самый рабочий вариант, это вставить флешку/диск с установочным файлом виндовс и оттуда отформатировать. Из системы никак:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если простыми словами - **система не даст вам себя убить ее же средствами**. Вот есть [гайд](https://www.diskgenius.com/how-to/how-to-format-c-drive.php) по вашему вопросу. Вообще это странно форматировать диск на котором система :)

Comment: Да это понятно, есть куча простых способов) Тут просто спортивный интерес: всегда думал, что можно снести систему средствами самой системы, а попробовал - оказывается нельзя)

Comment: @User_0, она не хочет умирать, это нормальное явление)) вы бы себя тоже не дали убить вашими средствами))

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый нажав на галочку слева от ответа.